# Cascading the bind (`>>=`) operator

Tags: haskell, monads, code-translation, do-notation

I have the following function

```
bar :: (Monad m, Num b) => m b -> m b -> m b -> m b 
bar x y z = do
              x' <- x
              y' <- y
              z' <- z
              return $ x' + y' + z'
```

and I'm trying to write it without the '`do`' block. I tried

```
bar' :: (Monad m, Num b) => m b -> m b -> m b -> m b
bar' x y z = x >>=  ( \x' -> y >>= (\y' -> z >>= (\z' -> (x' + y' + z') ) ))
```

But I can't get it to work - I get

> ```
>   error:
>     * Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ m b
>     * In the expression: x' + y' + z'
> ```

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot the return `x >>=  ( \x' -> y >>= (\y' -> z >>= (\z' -> return (x' + y' + z') ) ))`

Comment: Good point ... thanks!!

Comment: Who is voting to close this as "Cannot reproduce, or simple typo"? This is obviously very easy to reproduce, and forgetting `return` is a clear semantic issue, not a slip of the finger.

Comment: @GilShafriri it is perfectly OK to self-answer your question if you've realized what  the error was and how to fix it now.

Comment: I'm not sure why the downvotes? "Here's my problem" - Check. "Here's what I tried" - check. "Here's what happened" - check.

Comment: @amalloy "can *no longer* reproduce". If it's a very common mistake that is easily pointed out in a comment (as Garrison did), I'm comfortable defending the close vote.

Comment: @amalloy If it makes the asker feel "oh *duh*, silly me!" then it's a simple typo. If the asker needs an explanation about what `return` does and why you need it, then it's not a simple typo.